# What does ; random string ; represent in C

Tags: c, string

Semicolon stands for termination of statement in C, but what allows the code

```
; " int Just a random string " ;
```

to compile even without warnings and causes a trouble in

```
; int Just a random string ;
```

Which rules are involved here ?

Comment: For the same reason `1 + 1;` doesn't give an error.

Comment: "Semicolon stands for termination of statement in C" No. The semicolon **makes** an expression become a statement.

Comment: The previously answered question dosen't answers second part of question, this isn't DUPLICATE.

Comment: Without context, the question makes no sense. The meaning of "excessive" semicolon(s) depends on the surrounding context. It can stand for an empty statement (which is legal in C), or for an empty declaration (which is illegal in C, but allowed by some compilers).

Answer (score 2):

The two semicolons `;;` represent an empty statement.

This construction

```
; " int Just a random string " ;
```

represents an expression statement that has no effect.

This construction as is

```
; int Just a random string ;
```

is invalid.

As for the `for`-statement then its construction like this

```
for( ;; ) { /*...*/ }
```

means that all three expressions are omitted and the condition is implied to be always equal to `true`. You will get an infinite loop that can be interrupted by using some jump statement in its body (statement).

Comment: The same as in : for( ; ; )

Comment: You missed out the end part of the question

Comment: @cad I already updated the post. Now is it all correct?

Comment: Yes, yes, removed my comment too.

Comment: @BigO: No, in `for` they seperate expressions, they do not make the expressions become statements.

Comment: @vlad why `; int Just a random string ;` is invalid ?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `condition is implied to be always equal to true`,what causes this implication and how it's implied ?

Comment: @BigO It is simply made by convention.:)